# Custom List sharepoint

Tags: 2007

I have requirement in a custom list, some columns should be read only for some users and should be editable for the other users.

It looks like there is no way to implement this feature in MOSS 2007 apart from buying some third party tools.

Is there any way we can do this.? Has any one have done without object model coding?

Please let me know..

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but it takes planning.  You first have to lock down the views, so the users can't simply create a view and take it into datasheet mode and change the data.  Next, you'll want to customize the content type for the list.  After you've locked down the permissions to views and deletion(if required), then make custom forms and only expose these columns during different phases of entry.

You would also want to consider locking the form down in a document library as well.  So the URL isn't simply copied and pasted from an email or something along those lines.  Users will subvert the system if you let them!  You should have a look at my blog post about [locking down views](http://mattbramer.blogspot.com/2010/05/security-trim-list-views-with-ease.html) for more info about page security.  Ping me if you need more advice.

Comment: Hi iOnline, Many thanks for replying to my answer. I need more help on this could you kindly advise me on this issue.My initial approach is I have created a custom list and added the same list in new aspx sharepoint designer. Added some validation with jqery. And have to let the view should be filled by some users, once they submit this they cannot edit any of the data. Administrator has to login and see the applications from all other users. These are the only people who canedit this list items(only some columns like status field). They should be able to export into spreadsheet.

Comment: For SP2007 or WSS 3.0, there is a feature you can deploy that will allow you to assign permissions via workflow.  http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/  With that, you can allow users to create new items and then set perms on the items to only allow the admins to edit.  If you can't install this, then you *could* dip into web services via http://spservices.codeplex.com/ and set the permissions during the item creation.  I wouldn't recommend that b/c if it has to be secure, I wouldn't code the client to update their own perms.  It could be exploited.